# Simba ODBC driver to Bigquery connection error

Tags: google-bigquery

I am having issues establishing DSN connection to google bigquery using SIMBA ODBC driver.

The issue seems to be in connecting to REST API.  I installed a driver from CData to connect to big query and i am able to read data perfectly fine. Not sure what i am doing wrong with SIMBA driver.

Error Message 
"[Simba]DriverOAuthSupport Error Interacting with REST API:Couldnt connect to Server "

Error message pops up after successfully signing into Google account and getting confirmation code. Unable to get refresh token.

Below OAuth Mechanism used and error seems to be the same.

1. Service Authentication
2. User Authentication

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the driver? According to the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers), there were some fixes in the latest version.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, Thanks for your repy. Yes i am using the version "2.2.3.1002" downloaded from the Google wesbite.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?